# ajax problem - function on server is not called

Tags: ajax, hooks

This is a plugin for a specific shipping method for woocommerce.

I'm trying to add a form into a new shipment method for WooCommerce I create. In that form I wan the user to enter street and postal code and then press Ok-button. The click should pick up value from street and postal_code and then return a delivery location from DHL based on those values.

It's no problem to execute the click event when clicking on the button (in javascript), but the javascript then runs an ajax-call that do fail and returns 400 bad gateway.

I know that the reason is that the rows:

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_checklocation', array ( $this, 'location') );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checklocation', array ( $this, 'location') );
```

does not get registered for some reason, but I don't know why? Is the code located in wrong location of code? Or something else that I am missing? The location function is simply never called even if my ajax-call in my javascript looks like this:

```
var check_dhl_location = $.ajax({            
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                action: 'checklocation',    
                dhlsweden_shipping_adr: shipping_adr,
                dhlsweden_shipping_postalcode: shipping_postalcode 
            },
            url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

Please help me with a clue or even better a solution :-) Down below is nearly all code:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No access allowed!' );

//Check if WooCommerce is active
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    function dhlsweden_shipping_method_init() {
            if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Shipping_DHLsweden' ) ) {
                    class WC_Shipping_DHLsweden extends WC_Shipping_Method {

                            const client_key = 'I wont tell here!!!'; //Client-key is genereated in DHL Dashboard 

                            const base_url = 'https://api.freight-logistics.dhl.com/';
                            const homedelivery_url = 'homedeliverylocatorapi/v1/';
                            const ping = 'homedeliverylocator/ping';

                            const servicepointlocator_url = 'servicepointlocatorapi/';
                            const nearest_servicepoints = 'servicepoint/findnearestservicepoints';

                            /**
                             * Constructor for your shipping class
                             *
                             * @access public
                             * @return void
                             */
                            public function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) 
                            {          
                                //Initate ajax-functionality both admin and frontend
                                add_action( 'wp_ajax_checklocation', array ( $this, 'location') );
                                add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checklocation', array ( $this, 'location') );  

                                $this->load_js();



                            }



                            /* THIS function is NOT called */
                            public function location() {
                                $location = array();
                                /*
                                 * $shipping_adr =  filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'dhlsweden_shipping_adr' );
                                $postal_code = filter_input( INPUT_POST , 'dhlsweden_shipping_postalcode' );
                                */


                                error_log($shipping_adr, 3, 'dhlsweden.log');
                                error_log($postal_code, 3, 'dhlsweden.log');
                                error_log(print_r($location,true), 3, 'dhlsweden.log');


                                echo json_encode($location);
                                wp_die();
                            }



                            public function api_getlocations() { 
                                $fieldset = WC()->checkout()->checkout_fields;   
                                //var_dump($fieldset);
                                $shipping_adr = WC()->checkout()->get_value('shipping_address_1');
                                $postal_code = WC()->checkout()->get_value('shipping_postcode');

                                //Default values
                                if (!isset($shipping_adr) || !isset($postal_code)) 
                                {
                                    //Form with ajax functionality
                                    $form = '<form id="frmGetLocations" action="" name="">';
                                    $form .= '<input type="text" id="dhlsweden_shipping_adr" name="dhlsweden_shipping_adr" placeholder="Ange gatuadress">';
                                    $form .= '<input type="text" id="dhlsweden_shipping_postalcode" name="dhlsweden_shipping_postalcode" placeholder="Ange postnr">';
                                    $form .= '<input type="button" id="dhlsweden_button_shippinglocations" name="dhlsweden_button_shippinglocations" value="Ok">';
                                    $form .= '</form>';


                                    $form .= '<select id="dhlsweden_delivery" name="delivery">';
                                    $form .= '</select>';

                                    return array('userform' => $form);   //This function returns array only                                  
                                }
                                $adr_arr = explode(' ', $shipping_adr);
                                $street = $adr_arr[0];
                                $street_number = $adr_arr[1];


                                //var_dump($fn2);                                


                                $api_url = self::base_url . self::servicepointlocator_url . self::nearest_servicepoints;       
                                $addr['address'] = array(
                                            'street' => $street,
                                            'streetNumber' => $street_number,
                                            'additionalAddressInfo' => '',
                                            'cityName' => '', 
                                            'postalCode' => $postal_code,
                                            'countryCode' => ''
                                );
                                $feature_codes = array('featureCodes' => array(''));
                                $bit_cat_codes = array('bitCatCodes' => array(''));
                                $max_nr_items = array('maxNumberOfItems' => 0);

                                $json_data = array_merge($addr, $feature_codes,$bit_cat_codes,$max_nr_items);
                                $jd = json_encode($json_data);       
                                /*
                                 * var_dump($jd);
                                 */

                                //Response from DHL server
                                $dhl_response = wp_remote_post(
                                    $api_url ,
                                    array(
                                        'headers' => array( 'client-key' => self::client_key, 'accept' => 'text/plain', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json-patch+json' ),
                                        'body' => $jd
                                        ) //Client-key is genereated in DHL Dashboard 
                                    ); 
                                $json_arr = json_decode($dhl_response['body'],true);

                                $service_points = array();
                                foreach($json_arr['servicePoints'] as $sp) {
                                    $service_points[] = array('id' => $sp['id'],
                                                              'name' => $sp['name']);                                           
                                }                                
                                return $service_points;


                            }


                            /**
                             * Init your settings
                             *
                             * @access public
                             * @return void
                             */
                            function init() {
                                    // Load the settings API
                                    $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API. Override the method to add your own settings
                                    $this->init_settings(); // This is part of the settings API. Loads settings you previously init.
                                    // Save settings in admin if you have any defined

                                    $this->supports = array(
                                                                'settings',
                                                                'shipping-zones',
                                                                'instance-settings',
                                                                'instance-settings-modal'                                            
                                                            );

                                    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );                                     




                            }       


                            public function load_js() {
                                wp_enqueue_script(
                                        'dhlswedenjs',
                                        plugins_url('/js/wibergsweb.js', __FILE__)                                        
                                );

                                wp_localize_script( 'dhlswedenjs', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); //Frontend ajax url                                



                            }        



                            /**
                             * calculate_shipping function.
                             *
                             * @access public
                             * @param mixed $package
                             * @return void
                             */
                            public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {
                                    $this->add_rate(
                                                array(
                                                        'label'   => $this->title,
                                                        'cost'    => 0,
                                                        'taxes'   => false,
                                                        'package' => $package,
                                                )
                                        );
                            }


                    }
            }
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_shipping_DHLSweden' );

        function add_shipping_DHLSweden( $methods ) {
        $methods['dhl_sweden'] = 'WC_Shipping_DHLsweden';
        return $methods;
    }
        add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'dhlsweden_shipping_method_init' );


        function shippingmethod_template($template, $template_name, $template_path) {
            if ($template_name == 'cart/cart-shipping.php') {               
                $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php';
            }
            return $template;
        }
        add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template', 'shippingmethod_template', 20, 3);        




}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to execute an ajax-call (Ive done this before but not in a "shipping-method-context")

My javascript-file looks like this:

```
$('#dhlsweden_delivery').hide();
$('#dhlsweden_button_shippinglocations').on('click', '', function() {

    var shipping_adr = $('#dhlsweden_shipping_adr').val();
    var shipping_postalcode = $('#dhlsweden_shipping_postalcode').val();

    alert(shipping_adr);
    alert(shipping_postalcode);

    var check_dhl_location = $.ajax({            
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            action: 'checklocation',    
            dhlsweden_shipping_adr: shipping_adr,
            dhlsweden_shipping_postalcode: shipping_postalcode 
        },
        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    check_dhl_location.done(function(content_data) {
        alert('ok!');
        console.log( content_data );
    });

    check_dhl_location.fail(function(ts) {    
        alert('Något fallerade');

      alert(ts.responseText);
    });

});
```

Comment: Have you tried using the more modern/easier/debuggable REST API instead? The REST API tells you errors in readable plain language, unlike the ancient WP Admin AJAX that says nothing. It also implements a lot of security for you out of the box and gives you a pretty URL, e.g. `/wp-json/foo/v1/bar`, and works almost exactly the same on the frontend

Comment: I would also strongly advise against defining a PHP class inside a PHP function, it will cause lots of problems

Comment: @TomJNowell - Thanks for the tips. I did that way so I got the shipping method working. I understand now when you type that this is not a very good way of achieving this. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the shipping method isn't initialised when you make an ajax call. Try moving your actions directly into your init function. EG:

```
function checkAjax(){
    print_r($_POST);
    exit;
}
function dhlsweden_shipping_method_init() {
    //use checkAjax since you don't have access to your shipping method class. If this is the case then you need to rework your code
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_checklocation', 'checkAjax' ); 
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checklocation', 'checkAjax' );  

    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Shipping_DHLsweden' ) ) {
        class WC_Shipping_DHLsweden extends WC_Shipping_Method {    
           ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! It's worth checking! I'll get back to you later!

Comment: Thanks for putting my in the direction. I had to move add_action ajax hook outside of the function! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, glad I could help :-)